# Bash script to execute generated launch background processes

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script to launch several jars in a directory simultaneously.  The issue I'm having is getting these to launch as background processes.

All I've been able to do is get the first process to launch, then hang indefinitely.  What's strange is that the commands being generated and executed behave as expected when executed explicitly (copy/paste into a shell or create and execute them in a file).  This isn't doing anything crazy (I think?).  The intent is to get a list of jars in a local directory and launch them as background processes.

Here's the relevant piece that I'm having issues with:

```
jars=(`ls ${appDirectory}/*jar`)
for j in ${jars[@]}; do `java -jar ${j} 2>&1 > /dev/null &`; done;
```

Any ideas on what the issue might be?  Am I stuck on something with pipes?  Is there some black magic I need to be performing to launch background processes from within a shell?  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What's with the backticks inside the loop? Do you really mean to execute what the command prints? Also, [don't use `ls` like that](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Discarding all output means you are totally in the dark if there are ever errors.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part.  One of my latest edits in my hopeless attempts to get this working.  As for the comment regarding dumping logs, I completely agree, but I left that bit out to resolve my more immediate concern, which is to have something to create logs in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you mean is

```
for j in ${appDirectory}/*.jar;
do
   java -jar ${j} 2>&1 > /dev/null &
done
```

considering you don't have spaces in filenames.

Comment: Ok, wow.  That works just as expected.  Thanks!    Any idea what went wrong with my approach?  That part is still not terribly clear to me.  I'm hoping to get a better understanding of what I'm missing here.

Comment: Why not quote `appDirectory` and `j` and also take care of spaces in filenames?

Comment: Looks like, from what I posted here, the issue was with back ticks.  The initial approach I had was having issues with how it was iterating over the elements in the array created in the first line.  Either way, this approach solves the issue.  Thanks again for the second pair of eyes.

Comment: I suspect the redirects should be in the other order, i.e. `> /dev/null 2>&1` (assuming the goal is to discard both stdout and stderr). See [BashFAQ #55](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055).

Answer (score 0):

dtmilano has already given a solution to the problem; I'd like to explain why the problem was happening. The root cause was the backquotes in this part of the command:

```
`java -jar ${j} 2>&1 > /dev/null &`
```

What backquotes do in the shell is capture the output of the enclosed command, and use it as part of a new command (or in this case an entire command). Thus, it fires off `java -jar ${j} 2>&1 > /dev/null` in the background but tries to capture its output. Contrary to what you might think, `2>&1 > /dev/null` does not send both stderr and stdout to /dev/null; it redirects the command's stdout to /dev/null, but the command's stderr gets sent to the outer level's stdout instead. Thus the backquote expression winds up capturing java's stderr. And that means it has to wait until the java instance exits to make sure it's got everything.... even though java is in the background.